# Get default value for Locale Information Constants

Tags: c, winapi

With a C program on Windows, I want to obtain the default value of the decimal separator for a given locale. For example, if I use the following code:

```
GetLocaleInfoEx(L"it-IT", LOCALE_SDECIMAL, wcBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

I get the value ",".

If I change the decimal separator in the system's region settings to "k", the same function will return "k".
[image]

Is there a way to always obtain the global default value ("," in my example)?

Comment: The [combining constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-information-constants#combining-constants) section in the documentation lists, among others, the `LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE` constant. That's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for.